# New DDR3 Memory for Mac Mini

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, upgrade, memory, mac-mini

I bought a Mini last year and I want to update the RAM.

I was shopping around to find some compatible memory and found ([this](http://www.clasf.pe/kingston-ddr3-4gb-kvrd3n94g-en-lima-1655261/))from a Spanish retailer. They are selling what you see on the picture and I'm trying to understand if this memory is compatible with my machine or not.  I wrote to the company and they said that there will be no problem but I want to be super-sure.

This info is about my mac:

2.3 GHz Intel Core i5
2 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
And running OS X Lion.

Can anyone let me know if this memory is definitely compatible? Or advise on what else I am able to use?

Comment: Check out this offer: http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/1333DDR3S04S/

-- why are you upgrading RAM? Why not 8GB?

Comment: I would strongly advise 2x8GB as well. You don't want to end up in a situation down the line where you have to throw out 2 perfectly good 4GB modules just to make room for 8GB ones.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually specify the model of your Mac Mini, but by going off the data from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini), I think you have the mid 2011 model (Mac Mini 5,1).

If that is correct, then Apple's [technical specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp632) on this model confirm that the Mac Mini uses 1,333 MHz DDR3, up to 8 GB (4 GB x 2).

***HOWEVER***, that memory that you linked to is "DESKTOP" MEMORY, a DIMM ([dual in-line memory module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIMM)). The Mac Mini uses "laptop" memory, SODIMMs ([small outline dual in-line memory module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM)).

Comment: The OP said purchased LAST yer (2013)

Comment: OP listed date of purchase conflicts with the processor specs (the only mac mini with a 2.3Ghz is the mid 2011). I took the processor info to be more accurate than the "last year claim" (it's more precise, and harder to mistakenly guess a valid processor spec combination, whereas any date given can be valid)

Comment: Good point so it might be a used one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the Kingston RAM module in the picture then no, it won't fit a Mac Mini, this RAM module in the picture is too long, the Mac Mini requires 204 pin module, what you have in the picture has too many pins.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5475

2012 model:

```
PC3-12800 DDR3 
Unbuffered
Non-parity
204-pin module
1600 MHz
```